# Python Embedding: Importing a Module existing in working directory returns NULL

Tags: python, c++

When importing Python modules in C++, scripts can be loaded from directories that were added absolutely  via `sys.path.append()`, but none that are located in the current working directory:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("import os");

PyRun_SimpleString("os.chdir(\"..\\..\\..\\python\")"); // change working directory

PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pFunc, * pArgs, * pValue;
pName = PyUnicode_FromString("script");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
if (pModule == nullptr){

    PyErr_Print();
    std::exit(1);
}
```

The python module to be imported ("script.py")  is located in the current working directory (tested via: `print(os.listdir())`), but `PyImport_Import(pName)` returns NULL.
If the script is in a directory that is located via an absolute path, added via `sys.path.append(\"C:\\filelocation\")`, it can be imported without any problems.

How can modules of the current working directory be imported?

Answer (score 0):

there are some bugs in your code like using old functions.

those functions:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("import os");
```

are useless since you can import sys and os inside the python script.

inside a python script:

script.py:

```
import sys
import os

#your python code goes here
```

this piece of code should answer your question

```
Py_Initialize();

PySys_SetPath(L"the path where the python script resides");

PyObject* mod = PyImport_ImportModule("script");
if (mod == nullptr)
{
    PyErr_Print();
    std::exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot better. But I can't use realtive paths, can I?

Comment: I believe you can use a relative path

Comment: Yes, they can be used. There was another problem with the imported modules.

Comment: Which problem did you face?

Comment: I'm getting a "ModuleNotFoundError" when importing for example numpy in my python files. I'm looking for a solution but until now I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: This is trivial because, I’m sure, you’re using MinGW for C++ and you’re using something else for python that’s why you get this error. But if you try to work with VC++ and python installed in VStudio, it will work

Comment: Aaah - I'm using Visual Studio. I've installed python 3.8 and got it from the official python-website.

Comment: You have to use python from visual studio then :) from the installer

Comment: I used python from visual studio but it did't work either. I realized with setting my path with PySys_SetPath() i had overwritten all my pathes to my python distribution (C:\\python38, etc.). When adding those it worked!